# How to open an .sql file locally?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, database-restore

I have an .sql file which is around 2 gb of size. I want to open the database locally on my laptop.

To do so I guess I have to install both the SQL server and the SQL client application on my laptop.

Can you please direct me to the appropriate installation packages and documentation on how to obtain this all (I will welcome any answer concerning Windows or Linux)?

I am sure the answer is not, but still, can I open the .sql file with MS Access?

Here are the first few lines of the .sql file

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'SQL_ASCII';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;
```

Comment: [2.3. Installing mySQL on Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installation.html)

Comment: What is in the SQL file? *.sql files are usually SQL scripts, but if it's that big in size it sounds like it has data in it. Are you sure it's not a CSV data file or something similar?

Comment: [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com) is a nice graphical client for Windows

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you using? You've tagged 3 different ones.

Comment: Please show us the first 10 (or so) lines of that file.

Comment: @mwan100 it's the whole database

Comment: @Martin Smith I use none of them. I just have that file of size 2 gb and have no SQL related software installed.

Comment: @Vahagn: Can you show us the first few rows of the file? Whilst Access certainly isn't on par with the SQL servers (eg MySql, MSSQL, PostgreSQL etc), there's no reason why you can't import this data into a table with Access.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for the link. Is there some automated installation wizard, which does the whole stuff? I just need to open that single file, so I don't want to pass that sophisticated installation process (if it is possible :))

Comment: You haven't yet explained why you want to "open" the file.  Is it just to examine some of the data? Do you need to have the data restored in its full relational form or do you just need to see a few records?  If the former, then you will have to install MySQL.

Comment: @mwan100 I have added the first few lines to the question text

Comment: @Jim Garrison Saying "open" i mean to read the data in that database i.e. to execute queries on that and see the results. And it would be great if I can do it with an apropriate GUI interface.

Comment: The sample you added is Postgres, so you will probably need to install PostgreSQL in order to load it.

Comment: mwan100 Access has a size limit of 2 Gb.  Also Access can't read those files directly but would need to go through the ODBC drivers.   Which would then require Postgres, etc to be installed so you might as well use their client tools to view the data for ad hoc purposes.   Now if you want to get fancier, such as users entering or reporting on data, then sure you could use Access.   But at this point I don't see any need.

Comment: @Tony: I suggested Access as a viable option before the OP edited to include the fact that it was a Postgres dump - as you can see in my answer below after the edit, I only suggested Access as a frontend tool considering the OP seemed familiar with it (or at least moreso than trying to deal with fully fledged SQL servers which, for a beginner, can be a lot more onerous if all you want to do is look at the data).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 2gb file you've got is a PostgreSQL Dump File (ie a dump of their entire database, schema, data and all).

I'd suggest you install PostgreSQL (note, you could use any database, but since it was dumped from Postgres, we can play it safe and try to restore to the same engine):

http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows <- Just download and install the One Click Installer if you're on windows

And then you will need to restore that dump file to a database:

This page will walk you through it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE

But it is essentially running the following:

```
psql db_to_restore_to < yourdump.sql
```

You'll then have the full database setup ready to be queried (and you can hook up to the PostreSQL database via Access too if you are used to Access or aren't familiar with writing SQL)

Comment: I am running '\i path_to_mydump.sql' from psql promt, but i am getting error message "C:: Permission denied"

Comment: @Vahagn: What path are you using? Make sure you use Unix style slashes (ie `c:/path/to/myfile.sql` instead of `c:\path\to\myfile.sql`)